# Haml injecting `%tr` tags in `%thead`

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, haml, tablesorter

I'm currently debugging a [jquery.tablesorter](https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter) application, where tables can be automatically augmented with a UX for sorting its contents. It requires a particular `<table>` schema:

```
<table id="foo" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>Col2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Notice the section under `<thead>`.

Here is the Haml file I'm testing with:

```
%table#foo.tablesorter
  %thead
    %th Col1
    %th Col2
  %tbody
    %tr
      %td 1
      %td 2
    %tr
      %td 3
      %td 4
```

However, this is the Html being generated:

```
<table id="foo" class="tablesorter">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

There is an extra `<tr>` in our `<thead>`! How should I go about sidestepping this? I'm sure Haml provides functionality for enumerating Ruby arrays into table rows, but I really need this to be more standard.

Comment: Haml is correct, you need a tr around the th.  A th is nothing more than a td with different semantics.  A tr is still required to wrap them

Comment: You still need a row.

Comment: @Rafael, so it's not injecting the `%tr`? What if you use a `.each do ...` block with a `%thead`?

Comment: Shoot, I'm sorry folks.

Comment: It _is_ producing standard HTML.  The only [valid descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/thead) of a `<thead>` is `<tr>`.

Comment: This isn’t Haml that is injecting the `tr`. Are you looking at the source in a browser inspector window? I suspect you are looking at the source after the browser has fixed it. (Haml also will print the `class` attribute before the `id` attribute).

Comment: @matt would you like to take the credit?